# Closing Browser After Failed Test

Tags: selenium, testing, webdriver, testng

I am running tests with WebDriver, when a test fails, the browser does not close. On a Windows machine this is a huge problem because I then have several instances of the IEDriver still running in the background.

I have tried a try/catch statement which doesn't seem to work either. If the test fails the browser still remains open. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The try catch statement looks something like this:

```
try
{
   Assert.something(something something dark side);
   driver.quit();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
   System.out.println(e)
   driver.quit();
}
```

My complete code is below:

```
public class ClickAddMedication 
{
Browser browser = new Browser();

public void addMedication(String driverName)
{
    //Open Browser and navigate to page
    WebDriver driver = browser.getDriver(driverName);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://someIP:8080/hmp_patient/index.html");

    //Click Add Medication button
    WebElement addBtn = driver.findElement(By.id("add-btn"));
    addBtn.click();

    //Verify Add Medication page has loaded successfully
    WebElement rxBtn = driver.findElement(By.className("icon-rx"));
    WebElement otcBtn = driver.findElement(By.className("icon-otc"));
    WebElement herbBtn = driver.findElement(By.className("icon-herb"));

    Assert.assertEquals(true, rxBtn.isDisplayed());
    Assert.assertEquals(true, otcBtn.isDisplayed());
    Assert.assertEquals(true, herbBtn.isDisplayed());

    driver.quit();

}

@Test(groups = {"functionalTests.FF"})
public void test_AddMedication_FF()
{
    addMedication("firefox"); 
}
@Test(groups = {"functionalTests.iOS"})
public void test_AddMedication_iOS()
{
    addMedication("iOS");
}
}
```

I run the tests with a testng.xml file and would like to have the browser close regardless of whether or not the test passes.

Below is my `Browser` class:

```
public class Browser 
{
public WebDriver getDriver(String driverName)
{
    WebDriver driver = null;
    if(driverName == "firefox")
    {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }
    else if(driverName == "chrome")
    {
        File chromeFile = new File ("C:/webdrivers/chromedriver.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeFile.getAbsolutePath());
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }
    else if(driverName == "ie")
    {
        File ieFile = new File("C:/webdrivers/IEDriverServer.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", ieFile.getAbsolutePath());
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    }
    else if(driverName == "iOS")
    {
        try 
        {
            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:3001/wd/hub"), DesiredCapabilities.ipad());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) 
        {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    return driver;

}
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You haven't mentioned what framework you're using for executing your tests, but one way to handle this would be to use the equivalent of an "after test" annotation to accomplish this. JUnit calls this annotation `@After` while TestNG calls it `@AfterMethod`. The method annotated with the after test annotation will run after each method annotated with `@Test`, regardless of the pass/fail state of the test. If you are expecting to use the same driver instance across test methods, most test runners have an `@AfterClass` annotation or similar, which will run at the end of all `@Test` methods in the class.

As an example, you'd want to do something like the following (note the promotion of the `driver` variable to a member variable in the class):

```
public class ClickAddMedication 
{
    // N.B. For this approach to work, you *must* have the "driver"
    // variable here. Having it as a member variable of the class is
    // what allows the addMedication() method to access it for manipulating
    // the browser, and the tearDown() method to access it for closing
    // the *same* *browser* *instance*.
    WebDriver driver;
    Browser browser = new Browser();

    public void addMedication(String driverName)
    {
        //Open Browser and navigate to page
        driver = browser.getDriver(driverName);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http://someIP:8080/hmp_patient/index.html");

        //Click Add Medication button
        WebElement addBtn = driver.findElement(By.id("add-btn"));
        addBtn.click();

        //Verify Add Medication page has loaded successfully
        WebElement rxBtn = driver.findElement(By.className("icon-rx"));
        WebElement otcBtn = driver.findElement(By.className("icon-otc"));
        WebElement herbBtn = driver.findElement(By.className("icon-herb"));

        Assert.assertEquals(true, rxBtn.isDisplayed());
        Assert.assertEquals(true, otcBtn.isDisplayed());
        Assert.assertEquals(true, herbBtn.isDisplayed());
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown()
    {
        driver.quit();
    }

    @Test(groups = {"functionalTests.FF"})
    public void test_AddMedication_FF()
    {
        addMedication("firefox"); 
    }

    @Test(groups = {"functionalTests.iOS"})
    public void test_AddMedication_iOS()
    {
        addMedication("iOS");
    }
}
```

Comment: I put the following in after my `@Test` methods and the browser still did not close. This is Java with TestNG. `@AfterTest
 public void closeDriver(String driverName)
 { 
  WebDriver driver = browser.getDriver(driverName);
  driver.quit();
 }`

Comment: With the above, even if the test passes the `driver.quit()` is not working.

Comment: You'll need to provide more code to get a more precise answer, then. You'll have to show an entire class, with the `@Test` and `@AfterTest` methods, as well as give information about what `browser.getDriver()` does. For instance, if `browser.getDriver(driverName);` starts a new browser instance, then of course it won't work in your `@AfterTest` method.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have edited my question to have a complete test in it.

Comment: This is much more complete, however, you're still missing the contents of `Browser.getDriver()`. I suspect I know what the problem is, but without seeing that code, I can't be certain. I'll edit my answer here to give a "best guess", but my psychic debugging powers are taking a break today.

Comment: added the Browser class to my question.

Comment: Okay, given what your `Browser.getDriver()` method is doing (launching a new instance of the browser every time it's called), it's not surprising your attempt to call `driver.quit()` in the `@AfterMethod` method is failing. Your `closeDriver()` method in the first comment of this answer does, in fact, close an instance of the browser, it's just an instance that was created immediately prior by your call to `getDriver()`. You'll need to refactor your solution somewhat, either by exposing the `WebDriver` member as I've done, or by altering `getDriver()` to not create a new browser instance.

Comment: sorry not understanding your last comment.

Comment: `Browser.getDriver()` launches an instance of the browser every time it's called. Your initial implementation of `closeDriver()` (found in one of your earlier comments to my answer) calls `Browser.getDriver()`, which means it's launching a new instance of the browser (**not** the same one you used in your `addMedication()` method), and immediately quits it.

Comment: so I understand that, how do I get it to quit the driver regardless of pass or fail? Currently I just have a `driver.quit();` at the end of the test but that does not close the browser, even with a `try/catch` block it is not closing the browser.

Comment: Once again, you want a method marked with the `@AfterMethod` annotation. Inside that method, you call `driver.quit()`. It will run regardless of the pass or fail of the test case. The important part is this: your `driver` variable **has** to be a member of the test class. You can't access it using your `Browser.getDriver()` method, not without refactoring your `Browser` class, anyway. Try the example in my answer, and see if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ruby and Test Unit, you could have something like this -

if you are sharing the wedriver browser session for multiple tests, and need to close the browser only at the end

```
def self.shutdown
    @driver.quit
    assert_equal [], @verification_errors
end
```

or if you want to close the browser after each individual test

```
def teardown
    @driver.quit
    assert_equal [], @verification_errors
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the apt solution, but i did this as workaround for the problem.

instead of `Try{}catch`... use `throws`: `throws java.lang.AssertionError` and quit the browser in the catch block, e.g:

```
public void testMethod() throws java.lang.AssertionError{

Assert.assertTrue(condition,Message);
}

catch(java.lang.AssertionError e){

e.printstactrace();

browser.quit();

Assert.fail();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

driver.close() should do the trick for you. Or setting a boolean flag and when the test fails, the boolean flag is set to true.

And then using driver.close() or System.exit(1) should work !!

Let me know if you have trouble with the above workaround.